# Using farbtastic colorpicker in Twitter Bootstrap's popovers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, color-picker

In a user interface based on [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) I have multiple buttons that should trigger a `popover` yielding a [farbtastic colorpicker](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/). At the moment I have attached it to the `<body />` tag and delegated it to the buttons:

**HTML**

```
<div id="body" style="text-align:center;">

<a class="btn" rel="popover">First</a>
<a class="btn" rel="popover">Second</a>

<div id="colorpicker">
    <input type="color" id="color" />
    <div class="my-farbtastic"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").popover({
        trigger: "click",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "Colorpicker",
        content: $("#colorpicker"),
        selector: "a[rel=popover]",
        html: true
    }).on("click", "a[rel=popover]", function() {
        $("#colorpicker").find(".my-farbtastic").farbtastic("#color");
    });
});
```

With this approach I have two problems:

- The popover does not appear next to the respective button, but is aligned with the `<body />` tag.
- The colorpicker only works when the popover is triggered for the first time. Afterwards all JavaScript-based functionality is lost.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JREtC/7/) for a live demo.

Thank you in advance for any helpful thoughts on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In between I solved the problem myself and this is what my solution looks like (also see [version 11 of the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JREtC/11/)):

**HTML**

```
<div id="body" style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="text" rel="colorpicker" data-tool="first" />
    <input type="text" rel="colorpicker" data-tool="second" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[rel=colorpicker]").each(function(i, input) {
        $this = $(input);
        return $this.popover({
            title: "Colorpicker <i class='icon-remove pull-right'></i>",
            trigger: "click",
            placement: "bottom",
            html: true,
            content: "<div id='colorpicker-" + $this.data("tool") + "'>"
            + "<div class='color-picker'></div>"
            + "</div>"
        }).on("click", function() {
            $this = $(this);
            $target = $("#colorpicker-" + $this.data("tool"));
            $target.find(".color-picker").farbtastic(function(color) {
                $this.val(color).css("background-color", color);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

About the first question, attach the event in the `.btn`

```
$(".btn").popover({
        trigger: "click",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "Colorpicker",
        content: $("#colorpicker"),
        html: true
    })
```

Comment: I tried this before and had me an empty popover. It is a lot more difficult to apply farbtastic this way, but I'd be glad to see a working example. Thank you anyway!